# Removing data with double loop using for next

Tags: excel, vba

The problem: I need to remove all URLs used on app. from the list so I can identify pages that can be removed without causing issues. URLs can be used in both app and on web

What needs to be done:
Find all urls that is used on the app. host and remove those rows so I end up with a clean list.

I've tried to do this double loop solution:
Logic: 
 1. Loop to Find app.
 2. If app. is found then fetch "url" value to variable url
 3. When url value is fetched do another loop to identify that url and remove the lines.
 4. Loop continues to all urls used on app. is removed.

As the code stand it removes everything from the table then gets an error because the worksheet is empty.
    Sub DeletePPDependant()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim pos As Integer
        Dim furl As Integer
        Dim url As String
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

```
    For i = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        pos = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(i).Value), LCase("app."))
        If pos > 0 Then
            url = Cells(i, 3).Value
            For j = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
            furl = InStr(LCase(rng.Item(j, 3).Value), LCase(url))
            If furl > 0 Then
                rng.Item(j).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Excel looks like this, just with 100k rows:

This is how the sheet looks

[image]

Comment: It would be better to describe (in words) what you try to accomplish... Do you have only the three columns as we can see in your picture? Are you sure that you want searching in all range cells? When a cell to the right match your criteria and entire row is deleted, it is not possible to have a reference to another cell on the deleted row. Dealing with iterations from bottom up works on rows. Otherwise, in some cases, you may receive that type of error... When delete cells from the row which still references other cells to be used by iteration.

Comment: I try to find all pages used on the app and remove them from the list. I know it's not the most effective code

Comment: There are countless examples and previous questions on deleting rows. More efficient to use `Find`.

Comment: It is not a matter of effectiveness... I cannot understand from your code what you want to accomplish. And your answer is something like "I want to live well"... This may mean a lot of things. When I asked the above questions I wanted you to better explain HOW do you want to use your code in order to accomplish your need...

Comment: Alright. I'll try to be more clear. 
I want to identify all "urls" used on "app." and remove those rows from the list. 
The way I've tried to do that is to find rows containing "app." Then fetching the "url" value from that row and doing another loop to remove all rows with that "url". But it seems there is an issue with my VBA coding skills resulting in an empty table and an error.